# how to insert data to db in magento

Tags: magento, insert, magento-1.7

I created a new module following with this [url:](http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/)

In my module i created a registration form.

So now i want to insert the data entered into my registration form.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these instructions about models and database access:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

This should get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom db table with a custom model and collection of this table. There are lots of way but this is the magento way.

This link will help you http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table